# How can I change default recovery interval for all RabbitMQ consumers in Spring Cloud Stream configuration?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

Documentation states that the default recovery interval is `5000ms` for RabbitMQ binder consumers.

RabbitMQ binder configuration properties are prefixed with `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.<channelName>.consumer`.

`recoveryInterval` is a property with default value of 5000ms. I would like to be able to change it for all consumers in the configuration.

I tried `spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.default.consumer.recoveryInterval=3000`. It didn't work. It's still ~5000ms.

How can I change it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's

```
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.default.consumer.recovery-interval=3000
```

(no `bindings.`).

What you have is configuration for a binding called `default`.